# Custom HTTP Error Page with Specific Code Page and One Template Error View Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-blade

I want to make template for all error HTTP view and just put code and massage on it in `error.blade.php` (using template for all code) but for 404, it must using `404.blade.php` (using default error template). I'm really confused to implement it and not found the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: i don't this this is best idea to show all error as `404`

Comment: 4xx and 5xx are different type of error. Its not a good idea to show all 4xx and 5xx error from a specific static page